# Bot framework v4 and adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I'm using Bot Framework V4. I would like to know if I need to install any NuGet packages to support Adaptive cards version 1.2

I tested with some video and image content.All are working. Wondering if V4 by default has support for latest adaptive cards version.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bot Builder SDK has nothing to do with Adaptive Cards. It's not up to the SDK to support a specific Adaptive Cards version, it's up to whatever application ends up rendering the Adaptive Cards. Even if the SDK did have a dependency on the Adaptive Cards NuGet package, that would be handled automatically and you wouldn't have to install it yourself. You can install the NuGet package for your bot if you'd like to use its C# types to help you manage Adaptive Cards dynamically in your code as an alternative to just using JSON, but that is not necessary.

Please refer to [my latest blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) to better understand using Adaptive Cards with the Microsoft Bot Framework.

Comment: Got it. I'm using https://www.qnamaker.ai/ for JSON. if I understand correctly, I just need to add correct version in JSON to support latest adaptive cards. FYI: My requirement is to to render video content in chat bot.

Comment: @ajeshrkurup - Please remember to accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Your image and video content is working since bot framework supports various media.
Adaptive card is a media in itself. You need to create content of adaptive card type and then you can render it inside any prompt dialog.

You can install Adaptive Card Nuget Package by typing the following in `Tools > Nuget > Package Manager Console` :

```
Install-Package AdaptiveCards -Version 1.2.4
```

Or you can also directly Install the package - `AdaptiveCards 1.2.4` from `Manage Nuget Package` option. 
Do not install - `Microsoft.AdaptiveCards`, it's an old version.

After doing this, you can refer [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) for using adaptive cards.